# Persistent Semaphore or Event

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

If there are dozens, or hundreds, of threads operating concurrently, which do not share information, except for a wall-clock time hack that advances only after all the threads have processed their individual work assignments (some threads may take much longer than others, depending on conditions of the data, and may have persistent child threads themselves), what is the correct way to set up and enforce that clock synchronization?  This would operate at faster than real time (a simulation).

I have created a multidimensional array of event handles, but after some pondering, this just seems wrong, too complex for the problem, and not smart.

Comment: Your requirements so far do not give a hint as if *any type of synchronisation* would be needed.

Comment: Going for hundreds of threads sounds like a system that's designed to be slower than necessary. Anyway, it sounds like you are looking for a synchronization barrier ([EnterSynchronizationBarrier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706889.aspx)).

Comment: And if that doesn't work for you, you could just use two manual-reset events, one for the even ticks and one for the odd ticks.

Comment: Yes, there would eventually be a messaging system that would be triggered periodically, and synchronization would allow messages to be delivered with proper latency, with respect to the simulated wall clock time.